# Is there any example, where cooperative behaviour of predators induce fear in prey population?

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, population-dynamics, population-biology

I am basically from math background and doing Ph.D in mathematical biology. So I am not so efficient in biology. But my problem based on cooperative behaviour of animals during hunting which is related to the animal behaviours in ecology.

We know that different animals show cooperative behaviour during hunting (or, group hunting) such as wild dogs, lions, chimpanzees, birds, spiders, crocodiles etc. 
We also know that fear of  predator (predation risk) reduces the  growth rate of prey population. Now, I am looking for 
example(s), in which prey population does not fear predator but cooperative behaviour of predators induces (creates) fear in prey.

Comment: Are you asking for exemples when a particular prey species is "normally" not afraid of predators, unless/until the predators displays a (cooperative) behaviour to induce fear?

Comment: @fileunderwater  Yes, you got my point. Could you please give me any example related to this phenomenon?

Comment: So an animals that is to big for one predator, but is hunted by a group of predators would suit your case? Then a giraffe hunted by lions comes to my mind. A lion alone wouldn't attack a giraffe, but a pack does. And they induce fear because they are many and show huntig behaviour.

Comment: Are you asking a question about prey psychology or prey behavior?  i.e. is it "fearful" behavior that is your focus?

Comment: Maybe relevant, in relation to fear: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42497/are-there-any-animals-that-gradually-approaches-the-predator-to-search-for-food/42499#42499